# Atom editor not working showing failed to load snippets

Tags: atom-editor

Whenever I open my atom editor it always shows

> Failed to load snippets from 'C:\Users\invisible.atom\snippets.cson'
> C:\Users\invisible.atom\snippets.cson: missing / (unclosed regex)

What should I do how to get rid from this problem?

Comment: This question was easier to answer helpfully if the was a way to know the contents of `C:\Users\invisible.atom\snippets.cson`. Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If your snippets in `C:\Users\invisible.atom\snippets.cson` are not enclosed in quotations like this:

```
'prefix': 'printf'
'body': printf("$1\n", $2);
```

According [to this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/snippet-failed-to-load/48973/3), you should put the snippet inside `"` or `'`.

```
'prefix': 'printf'
'body': 'printf("$1\n", $2);'
```

If that still didn't work, try disabling all your packages as [suggested here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/snippet-failed-to-load/48973/6).